# Ambiguity with const keyword in C

Tags: c, string, constants

I have some code:

```
int main() {
    const char *string1 = "foo";
    char *string2 = "bar";

    string1 = string2;

    return 0;
}
```

When I build it, no warnings are raised. However, with

```
int main() {
    const char *string1 = "foo";
    char *string2 = "bar";

    string2 = string1;

    return 0;
}
```

A warning is raised:

```
warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
     string2 = string1;
             ^
```

With my current basic knowledge of C, I would have thought that `string1` would not be reassignable since it is `const`. To my surprise, it was the code in the first snippet that built with no warnings and the second code snippet the opposite.

Any explanations of what is going on? Thanks!

Comment: View it as: `(const char)* string1 = ..`. Note the warning “..from *pointer target* type..”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is perfectly ok to do. The (potential) problem here is that the strings you're pointing at are string literals, so modifying them would invoke undefined behavior.

What you're mixing it up with is probably this:

- `const char *str1` - str1 is a pointer to const char
- `char * const str2` - str2 is a const pointer to char
- `const char * const str3` - str3 is a const pointer to const char

`str1` can be reassigned to point at something else, but since it is a pointer to `const char` it cannot be used as an l-value, so `*str1 = <something>` is forbidden. `str2` on the other hand cannot be reassigned to point at something else, but it can be used as an l-value. With `str3` you cannot do any of those.

Also, note that `const char *str` and `char const *str` are equivalent. To find out what a declaration does, or to find out how to declare something, use this site: https://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 0):

> I would have thought that string1 would not be reassignable since it is const.

But it isn't!

It's a non-`const` pointer, pointing to a `const` thing (specifically, `const char`s).

The only reason your code is troublesome, is that you should not implicitly convert a `const char*` to `char*`, for fairly obvious reasons — it would defeat the purpose of `const`-safety to just drop `const` on a pointee type whenever you liked! That's why you're getting a warning.

Going the other way around, to *add* `const`ness, as in your first example, is fine.

**tl;dr: it's not your assignment; it's what you're assigning.**

Comment: It's perfectly ok to convert a const pointer to a non-const pointer.

Comment: @klutt I didn't say it wasn't. We're talking about the _pointee_ type. The question itself demonstrates that this doesn't work, and my answer says why.

Comment: (Well, okay, FSVO "doesn't work" ... seems this is merely a warning with a C compiler. It's a hard error in C++. It's definitely a bad idea.)

Comment: The question demonstrates that it emits a warning. Not that it does not work. And what to you mean with the pointee? The pointers are pointing at string literals whose type are non-const.

Comment: Yep, C++ has completely different rules than C when it comes to casting, so unfortunately, this answer is completely wrong.

Comment: You're still saying "It's a non-const pointer, pointing to a const thing" which is not true

Comment: Besides, the warning is not because the pointee is const. The warning is because string1 is a pointer to const, so your answer still contains pretty severe errors.

Comment: @klutt That's exactly what pointee means... the answer is precisely correct.

Comment: @klutt _"It's a non-const pointer, pointing to a const thing"_ That's exactly true. That precisely describes `const char*`. A const pointer to a const thing would be `const char* const`. Perhaps you're confused about placement of the keywords?

Comment: Exactly where in OPs code does any pointer point to something that is const? And no, it does not precisely describe a `const char*`. The accurate description is that it is a non-const pointer to const char, but it does not necessarily point to a const char.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with pointee. The way I have used it, is like this that `int a; int *p = &a;` then `p` is a pointer and `a` is a pointee. Do you agree?

Comment: @klutt _"Exactly where in OPs code does any pointer point to something that is const?"_ That is the very meaning of `const char *`. This conversation is pointless if you're going to reject the basic principles.

Comment: @klutt _"Please clarify what you mean with pointee"_ I didn't say pointee, I said pointee type, and its meaning is pretty obvious, no? Given `const char*`, the pointee type is `const char`. (And it doesn't matter whether the actual object being pointed to was created `const`; that's besides the point of propagating `const`-correctness, as I'm sure you know.) What exactly is confusing or complicated about this?

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that if we have this: `int x; const int *p = &x;` would you say that `p` is "pointing to a const thing"? I just want to be clear about what exactly you mean.

Comment: @klutt `p` is of type "non-const pointer to const int". That's it. Period. Simple! I'm going to move on now... have a good day.